# MemoryStream uses too much memory and doesn't dispose/close

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, memorystream

The memory usage goes up until it hits `System.OutOfMemory` exception. The MemoryStream instances count goes up until exception as well. I tried using `using()`, doing ms.Dispose(), ms.Close(), few other as well, GC.Collect(), etc.
Is this maybe a memory leak?

```
  while(running){ 
var screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen;
                using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(screen.Bounds.Width, screen.Bounds.Height)) {
                    using(var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)) {
                        g.CopyFromScreen(screen.Bounds.Left, screen.Bounds.Top, 0, 0, screen.Bounds.Size);
                    }
                    using(EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1)) {
                        encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, ssQuality);
                        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
                        ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = codecs[1];
                        using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                            bitmap.Save(ms, jgpEncoder, encoderParams);
                            image img2 = new image();
                            img2.Img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                            binF.Serialize(client.GetStream(), img2);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

VS Memory View:

[image: Memory View VS]

Task Manager memory usage of the process:

[image: Task Manager memory usage of the process]

Comment: I don't understand what the code is attempting to do. Take a screen shot and convert it to JPG? What is `binF`? What is `client`? Why would the number of `MemoryStream` instances go above one? I don't see a loop.

Comment: binF is BinaryFormatter and client is a TcpClient. Its in a while loop and its sending a screenshot over Tcp using BinaryFormatter.Serialize and its lowering its quality using EncoderParameters.

Comment: You also need to dispose the image returned from `Image.FromStream(ms);`, i.e. `using (image2 = Image.FromStream(ms)) { image img2 = new image { Img = image2 }; ... }`.  And you may need to rewind the memory stream before calling `bitmap.Save()`, e.g. `ms.Position = 0;`

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it for some reason it showed that MemoryStream was using all that memory. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dispose of image returned from `Image.FromStream(ms);`, e.g. like so:

```
ms.Position = 0; // Rewind the stream.
using (var image2 = Image.FromStream(ms)) 
{ 
    image img2 = new image { Img = image2 };
    binF.Serialize(client.GetStream(), img2);
}
```

This will ensure that, not only are the resources of the second image promptly disposed of, but also the `MemoryStream ms` is more likely to be promptly garbage-collected.  It is not happening currently because `Image` keeps a reference to the stream from which it was created.  This is alluded to in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_FromStream_System_IO_Stream_) which state:

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.